# regex: Java: match word between 2 spaces

Tags: java, regex, split

How can I extract the "id" from the following string using regex.

```
string = 11,"col=""book"" id=""title"" length=""10""
```

I need to be able to extract the "id" header along with the value "title".

outcome: id=""title""

I am trying to the use split function with a regex to extract the identifier from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String result = "col=\"book\" id=\"title\" length=\"10\"";
String pattern = ".*(id\\s*=\\s*\"[^\"]*\").*";
System.out.println(result.replaceAll(pattern,"$1"));
```

Cheers!

Comment: request clarification if you want it.

Comment: Unnecessary escapes. This is enough `".*(id\\s*=\"[^\"]*\").*"`

Comment: This is stand up to "unexpected" blank spaces by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pattern and Matcher classes to find what you are looking for. Try to find these regex `\\bid=[^ ]*`.

```
String data = "string = 11,\"col=\"\"book\"\" id=\"\"title\"\" length=\"\"10\"\"";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\bid=[^ ]*").matcher(data);
if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```